# Check weather predicted values follow the gaussian distribution or not using matlab?

Tags: matlab, gaussian, normal-distribution

I have used Gaussian Process for my prediction. Now let us assume I have predicted value store in `x` of size 1900 X 1. Now I want to check whether its distribution follow the gaussian distribution or not . I need this in order to compare the distribution functions of other methods predicted values like NN,KNN in order to judge which one is following smooth gaussian or normal distribution functions

How I can Do this ?  Better if I can get some result in the form of numerical data. the code is written as follows,
         `m = mean(ypred); % mean of r
s = std(ypred); % stdev of r
pd = makedist('Normal','mu',m,'sigma',s); % make probability distribution with mu = m and sigma = s
[h,p] = kstest(ypred,'CDF',pd); % calculate probability that it is a normal distribution`

The `ypred` value is the output obtain from `fitrgp` of matlab. Sample of `ypred` values are attached [here](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/674009/ypred.mat)

The [[figure][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJlbg.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJlbg.jpg) is a residual `qq_plot` of measured and predicted values.

Comment: I don't get it, if your prediction are based on a gaussian process: so by definition those data are normally distributed ? no ?

Comment: Yes, But I am comparing with other methods like NN,KNN and Want to know among them which one is following smooth gaussian or normal distribution functions

Comment: I did but I am looking for numerical result. QQ plot is all about graphical result.

Comment: True that. Then `kstest`is what you are looking for - but that one needs some knowhow to get it right. But frankly, a graphical analysis is just as valid as a numeric in this case.

Comment: But you won't be able to said: "Yes those data are normally distributed" or "No those data aren't normally distributed". A poisson distribution can be similar to a normal distribution. But you  can use the "Kolmogorov-Smirnov test" to test the probability of following normal distribution.

Comment: My supervisor looking for some numerical and some other graphical result so that our result should not only be judge by qq plot. Its not about ''Yes those data are normally distributed" but about ''relatively say x model prediction seems to be more gaussian than that of other methods'' This is what I want to convey

Comment: Any example of kstest ? Say if I have x is my predicted values then how can I apply this test. I have no idea.

Comment: I just checked this test with my methods. in two methods the value of p = 0 and h=1. What does this indicate ?

Comment: Well I have non linear model. So is this test work for nonlinear ? And in the test I written a code as [h,p] = kstest(predicted_values). Which is giving me zero

Comment: I also added residual qq plot. please have a look

Comment: Please read the doc, everything is clearly explained in the doc of the `kstest`. From the mathwork website: "The result h is 1 if the test rejects the null hypothesis at the 5% significance level, or 0 otherwise."

Comment: And How can I do this ? I have mean value of predicted of size 1900X1

Answer (score 0):

You can make a [One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/kstest.html):

```
x = 1 + 2.*randn(1000,1); % just some random normal distributed data, replace it with your actual 1900x1 vector.

m = mean(x); % mean of r
s = std(x); % stdev of r
pd = makedist('Normal','mu',m,'sigma',s); % make probability distribution with mu = m and sigma = s
[h,p] = kstest(x,'CDF',pd); % calculate probability that it is a normal distribution
```

Where `p` is the probability that it follows a normal distribution and `h = 1` if the null-hypothesis is rejected with a significance of 0.05. Since the null-hypothesis is "it follows a normal distribution", `h = 0`means that it is normal distributed.

Since `x` was in this example was sampled from a normal distribution, most likely `h = 0` and `p > 0.05`. If you run above code with

```
x = 1 + 2.*rand(1000,1); % sampled from uniform distribution
```

`h` will most likely be 1 and `p<0.05`. Of course you can write the whole thing as a one-liner to avoid creating `m`,`s` and `pd`.

Comment: The r value that u have used. Is this r value would be from my predicted values or measured input value ? If not then how can I put output result into the code . It seems from ur code u used for input values. How can I add my obtained predicted values into this code ?

Comment: I can see but my question was the variable u used is for input or predicted output result that I got which in this case is x ?

Comment: After using your code, I recieved these values from two methods are,  p = 6.5987e^-09 and p = 2.2983e^-11. What this indicates ? Is obtain p = 6.5987e^-09 method is more smooth than p = 2.2983e^-11 methods ?

Comment: Being normally distributed has nothing to do with being "smooth". It's just that some statistical methods require the data to be normally distributed to work properly. This output indicates that both datasets are very unlikely to be normally distributed.  Can you edit your question with what you actually exactly did? just to be sure you implemented it the right way

Comment: The qq plot is the plot of residual. I attached the code that I have written please have a look. I am sure the q plot is quite right but somehow the kktest coding is wrong.

Comment: This looks ok. looking at the qqplot i was very sure that p should be be far below 0.05, but I did not expect it to be that low. But then again it is difficult to guess a p-value from a qqplot.

Comment: To answer the question 2 comments before:  `p = 6.5987e^-09`  is "more" likely to be normally distributed than `p = 2.2983e^-11`. But both are far away following a normal distribution.

Comment: It should be Gaussian distribution not normal. I think we are making mistake there ?

Comment: gaussian distribution = normal distribution. It's a synonym